# Java script append table with ID

Tags: javascript, append

Having an issue with a little javascript, not using javascript so often.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">
        d3.text("#location#", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table",'myTable')

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to append the table with a specific ID

I have another javascript that makes me able to search the imported CSV file

```
function searchtable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var container = d3.select("body")
                  .append(  d3.creator("table").attr("id", "myTable")  );
```

or

```
var container = d3.select("body")
                  .append("table").attr("id","mytable")
```

Comment: Thanks this was the solution

`var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("table").attr("id","mytable")`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what result you expect but you might want to look into insertAdjacentHTML.

Ex:

```
let csvData = "Hello World!";
let tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
tbl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + csvData + '</td>' + 
    '</tr>'
 );
```